# awk compare one file with another file

Tags: file, awk, compare

I would like to grep for **aaa** and **bbb** and **ccc** from file1.txt in any order on the same line on file2.txt

file1.txt

```
aaa bbb ccc
ddd fff ggg
hhh ddd jjj
jjj ccc
```

file2.txt

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd fff ggg  --> output whole line since it matches with aaa bbb ccc of file1.txt
aaa ddd jjj hhh --> no output since it does not match with any search pattern in file1.txt
ccc ddd fff ggg jjj --> output whole line since it matches with jjj ccc of file1.txt
```

This is the script I came up so far. But does not output anything

```
gawk  'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,2$3]++;next} ($0 in a)' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: jjj ccc is on line 4 in file1.txt and there is no line4 in file2.txt so technically only the first line of file2.txt should be in the output

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue!  This is based on the example but not matching your description.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} 
              {for(i in a) {
                  m=1; n=split(i,b," "); {
                     for(j=1;j<=n;j++) 
                         if($0!~b[j]) m=0
                  }
                           }
              } m{print}' f1 f2
```

will result

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd fff ggg  --> output whole line since it matches with aaa bbb ccc of file1.txt
ccc ddd fff ggg jjj --> output whole line since it matches with jjj ccc of file1.txt
```

Note that line to line matching is not implemented as in your example.

Comment: It works for some reason but it outputs only one line of search pattern of file1.txt. The rest of matching lines are omitted.

Comment: @sdf , has your data passed thru Windows, either by source, editor or ftp (etc)? If so, the `dos2unix f1 f2 as_many_files_as_you_like`. Good luck.

Comment: @karakfa your script works, though it returns only the last entry of file1.txt

Comment: Finally with searching, reading and trying I got the desired code, thanks to karakfa's example code. `NR==FNR{a[c++]=$0;next} {for(i in a) { m=1; m=split(i,b," "); { for(j=1;j<=m;j++) if($0~b[j]) m=0 } } } m{print}`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 paste file1.txt file2.txt | awk -F '\t' '$1~/aaa|bbb|ccc/{ print $2}'
```

But as I mentionned in my comment there is a match on the 4th line of file1.txt but there is no 4th line in file2.txt so it won't print anything.

paste merge both file using a  as the separator. it then feeds the output of paste to awk using  as the separator and where `$1` is the line of file1 and `$2` is the line of file2.